# discord.py trying to set up a moderation log channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to set up a log channel where it will post a message in that whenever someone gets kicked. At the moment I'm storing it in a json file, but i cant get it tow work. Does anyone have the code? Here's mine:

```
with open('log_channels.json', 'r') as f:
      log_channels = json.load(f)

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def modlog(ctx, channel = None):
  log_channels[str(ctx.guild.id)] = channel.split()
  with open('log_channels.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(log_channels, f)
  await ctx.send(f'Mod log set to {channel}')

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
 await member.kick(reason = reason)
 await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title=f'{member} has been kicked.', color= 0xFF8633))
 guild = ctx.guild
 log_channels.get((guild.id) ('0'))
 print (log_channels)
 channel = client.get_channel(log_channels)
 await channel.send(f"test")
```

Comment: What do you mean by you can't get it to work, what happens? any errors?

Comment: Yeah, discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: And what line does it print for, you should provide the whole traceback in the question itself. btw read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from this line:

```py
log_channels.get((guild.id) ('0'))
```

And more precisely, from `(guild.id) ('0')`, which is equivalent to `123456789012345678('0')` and is impossible.

What you probably meant to do is this:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await member.kick(reason = reason)
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title=f'{member} has been kicked.', color= 0xFF8633))

    channel_id = log_channels.get(str(ctx.guild.id), '0')
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)

    await channel.send(f"test")
```

NB: `json` dict keys must be strings, so you need to get `str(ctx.guild.id)`.
Also, if `log_channel` equals `'0'`, `channel` will be `None` and `channel.send()` will raise an error.

What I would recommend doing is this:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await member.kick(reason = reason)
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title=f'{member} has been kicked.', color= 0xFF8633))

    if str(ctx.guild.id) in logs_channels:
        channel = client.get_channel(log_channels[str(ctx.guild.id)])
        await channel.send(f"test")
    else:
        # Not mandatory, you can remove the else statement if you want
        print('No log channel')
```

Comment: It came up with the error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. Would there be something wrong with how I stored the json data?

Comment: Could you include your json file structure in your question?

Comment: Why would `log_channels[str(ctx.guild.id)]` be a list? Do you have multiple log channels?

Comment: Do you know how to remove symbols from a number value?